# Adding selected item from one jList to another with a button press event.Not working

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

So i have two lists,one already populated and the second empty.And a button which when pressed gets the selected item from the first list(which I know is working because of the print statement) and then adds to it the second list but it doesnt seem working would appreciate any help.

```
flightsList = new javax.swing.JList();

flightsList.setModel(
  new javax.swing.DefaultListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "121", "105", "109"};
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(flightsList);

qList = new javax.swing.JList();

qList.setModel(
  new javax.swing.DefaultListModel() {
    String[] strings = { };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});

jScrollPane2.setViewportView(qList);

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  int selectedItemIndex = flightsList.getSelectedIndex();
  String selectedFlight = (String) flightsList.getModel().getElementAt(selectedItemIndex);
  DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) qList.getModel();
  System.out.println(selectedFlight);
  model.addElement(selectedFlight);
  qList.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: You need to create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get the best help.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a discussion on convention, using import would make your code significantly easier to read. However, you can directly update a JList using a ListModel. Any updates to the ListModel will affect the JList as well.

```
JList flightsList = new JList();
listmodel1 = new DefaultListModel();
flightsList.setModel(listmodel1);
String[] strings = { "121", "105", "109"};
JScrollPane1.setViewportView(flightsList);

qList = new JList();
listmodel2 = new DefaultListModel();
qList.setModel(listmodel2);
String[] strings2 = new String[3];
JScrollPane2.setViewportView(qList);

private void addButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)     {                                    
  String selectedFlight = (String) listmodel1.getElementAt(flightsList.getSelectedIndex());
  listmodel2.addElement(selectedFlight);
  System.out.println(selectedFlight);
}

public int getSize(String[] str) { 
    return str.length;
}

public String getElementAt(String[] str, int i) { 
    return str[i];
}
```